# Inequality proof trouble with the last step.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Question: Prove that if $y_0 \neq 0$ and $ |y-y_0 | <  \min \left( \dfrac { |y_0|} {2} , \dfrac { \epsilon |y_0^2|} {2} \right)$

Then $ y \neq 0$ and $ \left| \dfrac {1} {y} - \dfrac {1} {y_0} \right| < \epsilon $

I started with $ |y| - |y_0 | \leq |y-y_0 |< \dfrac { |y_0 |} {2}$

Leads to $-|y|<- \dfrac { |y_0 |} {2} \to |y|> \dfrac { |y_0 |} {2} \to \dfrac { 2} {|y_0 |} > \dfrac { 1} {|y|}$

Reducing $ \left| \dfrac {1} {y} - \dfrac {1} {y_0} \right| \to  \dfrac {|y_0 -y|} {|y| |y_0|} < \dfrac {2|y_0 -y|} { |y_0|^2}$

From here im half lost since $\dfrac {2|y_0 -y|} { |y_0|^2}< \dfrac { 2 \epsilon |y_0^2|} {2 |y_0^2 |} \to \epsilon$ is great but how do i know that it is min value of $ |y-y_0 | = \dfrac { \epsilon |y_0^2|} {2} $ and how do i prove that $ \dfrac { \epsilon |y_0^2|} {2} \leq \dfrac { |y_0 | } {2} $

I feel like the answer is already in my argument somehow it feels like my arguement implies that $y_0 <1 $ perhaps line two is what is providing me with this insight? $ |y| - |y_0 | < \dfrac { |y_0 |} {2}$

Anyway if someone can confirm what i have done as correct or incorrect and show me how to get to the correct proof; especially includiing why we know that.

$\min \left( \dfrac { |y_0|} {2} , \dfrac { \epsilon |y_0^2|} {2} \right) =  \dfrac { \epsilon |y_0^2|} {2}$

Thanks.

Comment: You have that $|y-y_0| < \frac{|y_0|}{2}$ *and* $|y-y_0| < \frac{\epsilon|y_0|^2}{2}$ that is what the min-condition says. Your proof seems fine as it is. (Sorry I misread your proof for my first comment)

Comment: im sorry i don't follow you when min = $y_0$ /2 i don't understand how the proof works

Comment: The condition $|y-y_0| < \min(|y_0|/2,\epsilon|y_0|^2/2)$ means that we have both $|y-y_0| < |y_0|/2$ and $|y-y_0| < \epsilon|y_0|^2/2$ (and we don't have to care which is smallest). First you use $|y-y_0| < |y_0|/2$ to get $\frac{1}{|y||} < \frac{2}{|y_0|}$ then you use the second condition $|y-y_0| < \epsilon|y_0|^2/2$ to show that $|1/y-1/y_0| = |y-y_0|/|yy_0| < \epsilon$. Nowhere do we have to assume anything about which one of the conditions are smallest (but we need both to hold to get the argument through)

Comment: What do you need this for? Maybe it doesn't have to be that ugly.